# Different view of shared link in facebook feed

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

We have facebook "Like" button on our pages.

After like it suggests to share the liked link.

This is how the liked link displayed in common friends feed (correct description and whole view):
[image]

This is how the link displayed in my private feed (no description):
[image]

The entire page has all required og-meta-tags. Facebook debugger tool says there are no errors.

Why is there no description for the links in private feed? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is facebook bug.
It happens only in "like + video" opengraph default story.

Posted a bug at facebook bugtracker: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/564356093638701

I see only one solution - use some another way of sharing